# Android: Parse push notifications with ParsePushBroadcastReceiver doesn't work

Tags: android, parse-platform, push-notification, broadcastreceiver, android-notifications

I followed the startup, I have a running application that reads and writes to parse, the problem is that I want the users to receive push notifications and I just can't get that to work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />

<permission android:protectionLevel="signature"
    android:name="com.messaging.application.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>
<user-permission android:name="com.messaging.application.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar"
    android:name="com.messaging.application.app.MyApplication">
    <activity
        android:name="com.messaging.application.app.LoginActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity 
        android:name="com.messaging.application.app.ListUsersActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.messaging.application.app.SignUpActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.messaging.application.app.ListFriendRequests"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.messaging.application.app.ListFriendsActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>
    <service android:name="com.messaging.application.app.MessageService"/>


    <service android:name="com.parse.PushService" />
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParsePushBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
    <receiver android:name="com.parse.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
            <category android:name="com.messaging.application.app" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <!--<receiver android:name="com.messaging.application.app.CustomReceiver"-->
        <!--android:exported="false">-->
        <!--<intent-filter>-->
            <!--<action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE"/>-->
            <!--<action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE"/>-->
            <!--<action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN"/>-->
        <!--</intent-filter>-->
    <!--</receiver>-->


    <activity android:name="com.messaging.application.app.MessagingActivity"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
    </activity>

</application>
```

and my build.grade

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.parse'

buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://maven.parse.com/repo' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.parse.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.messaging.application.app"
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
    compile files('libs/sinch-android-rtc-3.9.2.jar')
    compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-1.13.0.jar')
}
```

I have initialized parse in the `MyApplication` class with the installation.

```
public class MyApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Parse.initialize(this, "xxxx", "xxxx"); // replaced just for the question
        ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().saveInBackground();

    }
}
```

When I log in to parse, I press send notification with some simple text, but I don't receive a notification on my device. What could the problem be?

Comment: Are you connected to internet? Can you see your installation in the Installation table? And its deviceToken? Are you sending your push to right audience?

Comment: Hi, I am connected to the internet, in parse I can see the installation, I send the pushes to all users (which is only this 1) and I don't understand the deviceToken question. Could you please specify what that is?

Comment: Sure. In Installation table there is a column named deviceToken. It may be the cause of your problem if it is NULL.

Comment: It is <undefined>. would that make a difference?

Comment: Yes, that's the problem. Push is not sent because Parse can't identify your device. It is due to a bad configuration in your app.

Comment: How can that be resolved? I followed the parse tutorial from start to end, and i believe that I configured everything correct.

Comment: I found out that the deviceToken actually doesn't exist if the application is on android. That's what they wrote on Parse.com in the documentation. I don't receive push even when I submit it from the parse website. Could there be something else?

Comment: parse is shutting down. They have asked people to move to GCM. If you have already registred with GCM, you are missing `<meta-data android:name="com.parse.push.gcm_sender_id" android:value="id:XX" />`

Answer (score 0):

I think you have missed `ParseBroadcastReceiver`. That is the only diff I see between my configuration and yours. Try adding this to your manifest:

```
   <receiver android:name="com.parse.ParseBroadcastReceiver">
     <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
       <action android:name="android.intent.action.USER_PRESENT"/>
     </intent-filter>
   </receiver>
```

Check the `deviceToken` ;)

Hope it helps!

Comment: I added this receiver as well. I just can't find what is wrong with the ParseInstallation and why it ignores the deviceToken

Comment: I found out that the deviceToken actually doesn't exist if the application is on android. That's what they wrote on Parse.com in the documentation.